# MySQL Count and sort enhance query

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query but for the life of me can't figure out the proper syntax to sort by the largest count and only include a count of 5 or higher.  Basically I only want to display results that have 5 or more Offices in the COUNT and then sort by those with the largest count first?

```
SELECT COUNT(Offices) FROM Active GROUP BY Offices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(Offices) AS c FROM Active GROUP BY Offices HAVING COUNT(Offices) >= 5  ORDER BY c DESC
```

Comment: Getting error "Invalid use of Group function".  I removed the GROUP BY section and am still getting the same exact error?